How to transform a list in the following way?
Consider the following list:
dat = {{0., 0., 0., 0.0005, 0.0005, -11., 1., 1., 0.0314493, 0.00449589, 
  0.0150787, 0.0351659, 0., 12., 0., 
  1., -0.0150614, -0.0217332, -0.0313501, 0.0410123, 0., -14., 0., 
  1., -0.0163879, 0.0172373, 0.0162714, 0.0283218, 0., -1.23457*10^7, 
  0., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0.0005, 0.0005, -11., 1., 1., 0.00452546, 
  0.0252304, 0.0126144, 0.0285688, 0., 12., 0., 
  1., -0.0154355, -0.0343104, -0.0340328, 0.0507315, 0., -14., 0., 1.,
   0.0109101, 0.00907999, 0.0214184, 0.0251997, 0., -1.23457*10^7, 0.,
   1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0.0005, 0.0005, -11., 1., 1., 0.0430666, 
  0.00259126, 0.0240015, 0.0493713, 0., 12., 0., 
  1., -0.0368523, -0.00908171, -0.0264978, 0.0462893, 0., -14., 0., 
  1., -0.00621432, 0.00649045, 0.00249624, 0.00883943, 
  0., -1.23457*10^7, 0., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 0.0005, 0.0005, -11., 1., 
  1., 0.0329933, -0.00898041, -0.0300977, 0.045553, 0., 12., 0., 
  1., -0.032071, 0.00781574, 0.00394182, 0.0332441, 0., -14., 0., 
  1., -0.000922316, 0.00116466, 0.0261559, 0.0257028, 
  0., -1.23457*10^7, 0., 1.}};

Each of its rows may be represented as Join[list1,list2,...], where list has the structure
{n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8}

with n being some numbers. In each row, under Join[], I want to keep only the lists for which Abs[n6] is 12., 14., or 16.
So, the output should be
dat = {{0.0314493, 0.00449589, 
  0.0150787, 0.0351659, 0., 12., 0., 
  1., -0.0150614, -0.0217332, -0.0313501, 0.0410123, 0., -14., 0., 
  1.}, {0.00452546, 
  0.0252304, 0.0126144, 0.0285688, 0., 12., 0., 
  1., -0.0154355, -0.0343104, -0.0340328, 0.0507315, 0., -14., 0., 1.}, {0.0430666, 
  0.00259126, 0.0240015, 0.0493713, 0., 12., 0., 
  1., -0.0368523, -0.00908171, -0.0264978, 0.0462893, 0., -14., 0., 
  1.}, {0.0329933, -0.00898041, -0.0300977, 0.045553, 0., 12., 0., 
  1., -0.032071, 0.00781574, 0.00394182, 0.0332441, 0., -14., 0., 
  1.}};

Generically, each row of dat may have different numbers of the lists satisfying this requirement.
Could you please tell me how to do this?

I think it's easiest if you first partition your data into lists of 8 elements using Partition, and then delete those lists that do not match your criteria. For example:
Join @@@ DeleteCases[Partition[#, 8] & /@ dat, 
 lst_ /; ! MemberQ[{12., 14., 16.}, Abs@lst[[6]]], {-2}]


Well, Domen beat me to it, but with a slightly different approach.
Flatten@*Select[CurryApplied[MemberQ, 2][{12., 14., 16.}]@*Abs@*Extract[6]] /@ 
  (Partition[#, 8] & /@ dat)

